# Encoder into CNN Accuracy not Increasing using Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I've been trying to create a classifer for alzheimer's disease based on MRI images and classifying into one of 3 classes. No matter how many epochs I run my accuracy does not increase. It stays at 48.25% I've tried increasing the complexity of my CNN by adding more convolutional layers and pooling layers but the same result is occurring. I've also tried changing the latent dimension of the encoded image and the learning rate but nothing has changed other than the run time going through the roof.

Here is my code,

```
# Import needed libraries
import os
import math
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.utils import to_categorical

from tensorflow.keras import layers, losses, optimizers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
print('Libraries Imported')

# occasionally needed code to make code
# run on my computer to escape fatal error
#os.environ['KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK'] ='True'

# Set up directories and Constants
train_dir = r"C:/Users/rgeis/Senior Project/AD/Train_DATA"
test_dir = r"C:/Users/rgeis/Senior Project/AD/Test_DATA"
val_dir = r"C:/Users/rgeis/Senior Project/AD/Val_DATA"
BATCH_SIZE = 32
IMG_HGT = 150
IMG_WID = 150
NUM_CLASSES = 3
latent_dim = 625
shape = (IMG_HGT, IMG_WID, 3)

# Set up training dataset
train_datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    target_size=(IMG_HGT, IMG_WID),
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    class_mode='categorical',  # set to 'input'
    shuffle=False,
)

# Set up validation dataset
val_datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
)

val_generator = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    val_dir,
    target_size=(IMG_HGT, IMG_WID),
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    class_mode='categorical',  # set to 'input'
    shuffle=False,
)

# Set up test dataset
test_datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
)

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    test_dir,
    target_size=(IMG_HGT, IMG_WID),
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    class_mode='categorical',  # set to 'input'
    shuffle=False,
)

print('datasets created')

# Save labels
train_labels = train_generator.labels
val_labels = val_generator.labels
test_labels = test_generator.labels
print('Labels Saved')

# Encode labels in one-hot
train_labels_encoded = to_categorical(train_labels, num_classes=NUM_CLASSES)
val_labels_encoded = to_categorical(val_labels, num_classes=NUM_CLASSES)
test_labels_encoded = to_categorical(test_labels, num_classes=NUM_CLASSES)
print('Labels Encoded')

# Create Autoencoder class
class Autoencoder(Model):
    
    def __init__(self, shape, latent_dim):
        super(Autoencoder, self).__init__()
        
        # Set expected shape for autoencoder
        self.shape = shape
        
        # Set compressed dimensions
        self.latent_dim = latent_dim
        
        # Create encoder
        self.encoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
            layers.Input(shape=shape),
            layers.Flatten(), 
            layers.Dense(latent_dim, activation='relu'),
            layers.Reshape((1, 1, latent_dim)),
        ])
        
        # Create decoder
        self.decoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
            layers.Dense(np.prod(shape), activation='sigmoid'), 
            layers.Reshape(shape)
        ])
    
    # Run Autoencoder function
    def call(self, x):
        encoded = self.encoder(x)
        decoded = self.decoder(encoded)
        return decoded

# Create instance of Autoencoder
autoencoder = Autoencoder(shape, latent_dim)
print('Autoencoder made')

# Create CNN Model with additional Conv2D layer
cnn_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    layers.Input(shape=(1, 1, latent_dim)),
    layers.Reshape((int(math.sqrt(latent_dim)), int(math.sqrt(latent_dim)), 1)),
    layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation='softmax')
])
print('CNN Made')

# Define combined model
combined_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    autoencoder.encoder,
    cnn_model
])
opt = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.1)
# Compile combined model
combined_model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['Accuracy', 'Precision', 'Recall'])

reduce_lr = tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.2, patience=5, min_lr=0.0001)

# Train combined model
combined_model.fit(train_generator, epochs=10, steps_per_epoch=len(train_generator), validation_data=val_generator, validation_steps=len(val_generator), callbacks=[reduce_lr])

test_metrics = combined_model.evaluate(test_generator)
# Print metrics
print(f'Test loss: {test_metrics[0]}')
print(f'Test accuracy: {test_metrics[1]}')
print(f'Test precision: {test_metrics[2]}')
print(f'Test recall: {test_metrics[3]}')
```

I would really appreciate any help people are willing to offer.